# Best way to implement paging in queries

Tags: mysql

I would like to know the best way to implement paging in queries.

Currently, I am doing something like this:

```
SELECT
  columns
FROM
  (SELECT columns FROM table ORDER BY column)
WHERE
  rownum BETWEEN start AND end
```

Is this the best way to go about it?

Comment: what flavor of database are you using?

Comment: mysql (Gosh! Why do replies have to be 15 characters in length! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's the best way I know by far. If you are working with SQL Server, you may combine Row_Number and CTE together. Take a look at http://www.sqlteam.com/article/server-side-paging-using-sql-server-2005

and for MySQL

```
SELECT MyField
FROM sometable
LIMIT [offset], [pagesize]
```

of course you should replace [offset] and pagesize with appropriate values.

Comment: How do you know the OP is using SQL Server?

Comment: Well juliet, it's a sixth sense :) he mentioned rownum, and not many DBMS provides a function to get a row number :)

Comment: Hmm...I see. BTW, Am using mysql. Not sure if there are row_number or such other functions.

Comment: Well, you can use LIMIT statement for MySQL. I updated the post. check it out

Comment: Hmm...How will this method work with paging? Won't it just return the same set of records again and again?

Comment: you should change the offset according to page index. for example, if you have a page with 15 rows, the second page's offset will be 15 (or 15 + 1 dont remember now), third page's offset will be 30 and so on. This if I remembered correctly. many days I have not worked with mysql. you may need to refer to the documentation for additional details.

Comment: No problem. glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server I would use the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (SELECT TOP (@lim) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sometable.id ASC) AS row,
                                                                        sometable.id AS id,
                                                                        sometable.name as name
                    FROM sometable) as tratable
WHERE Row > @start AND Row <= @lim
```

Comment: Why `TOP (@lim)` *and* `AND Row <= @lim`?  Am I missing something?  Also why `DISTINCT`?

Comment: @Kirk Woll: In that case you can use the field 'row' to identify the rows in the paging.

Comment: Am using mysql. Even if it's sql server, am not sure if this is faster. It's the same that I have mentioned in my query. Right? Or am I missing something....?

Comment: What I meant was that if there are say 1 lakh records satisfying the given criteria, then they would all be selected in the given run, an order by would be done on them and then the required 10 or 20 or x number of records returned.